# Button in .py file not changing screen. main_app is not defined

Tags: python, kivy

So i want my button in the `start_func` to show a Trainingplan based on to which plan it refers to. I am doing so through my .py file but it doesn't work like i want it too. Also i had to create a lambda function on the same button because of the  `AssertionError: None is not callable` Error and i am not sure if i did it correctly so it would be nice if you could take a look at that too :) I know that the show_training function is working.

I tried to handle the error with Clock.schedule but it still doesn't work...

EDIT: I  just uploaded the code and trimmed as much as i could. If you navigate on the nav drawer to training plans the button show next to the plan should do the explained above but throws the problem explained above. Hope it is clear and you can work with that

whole py code:

```
    from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder

Window.size = (720, 1280)

import random
import main
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp

from alltrainingplans import *

picture_number = 2


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class TrainingPlans(Screen):
    pass


class SingleTrainingPlan(Screen):

    path_i = StringProperty()
    current_training = 1

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SingleTrainingPlan, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def show_training(self, current_training):
        list_training_plans = os.listdir("training_programs")  # dir is your directory path
        number_files = len(list_training_plans)
        print(number_files)
        print("added to recent trainings: " + str(main.TrainingApp.recent_trainings))

        training_path = [None]

        if current_training not in main.TrainingApp.recent_trainings:
            main.TrainingApp.recent_trainings.append(current_training)
            print("Added item to recents: " + str(main.TrainingApp.recent_trainings))

        if len(main.TrainingApp.recent_trainings) > 5:
            main.TrainingApp.recent_trainings.pop()
            print("Just popped last item of recents: " + str(main.TrainingApp.recent_trainings))

        if current_training in main.FavouriteTrainings.fav_plans:
            self.ids.fav_btn.background_normal = "ButtonPictures/star-2.png"

        else:
            self.ids.fav_btn.background_normal = "ButtonPictures/star.png"

        for training in range(1, number_files):
            training_path.append("training_programs/Unknown-" + str(training) + ".jpeg")

        self.path_i = training_path[current_training]
        print(self.path_i)

        self.current_training = current_training

    def add_plan_to_favs(self):
        if self.ids.fav_btn.background_normal == "ButtonPictures/star.png":
            self.ids.fav_btn.background_normal = "ButtonPictures/star-2.png"
            main.FavouriteTrainings.fav_plans.append(self.current_training)
            print("Plan Added, now:", main.FavouriteTrainings.fav_plans)

        else:
            self.ids.fav_btn.background_normal = "ButtonPictures/star.png"
            main.FavouriteTrainings.fav_plans.remove(self.current_training)
            print("Plan Removed, now:", main.FavouriteTrainings.fav_plans)

        main_app.fav_training_content.refresh()


class FavouriteTrainings(Screen):
    fav_plans = []

    def do_something(self):
        print("I'm now in my favorites")
        print(self.fav_plans)
        pass

    pass


class NavigationDrawer(Screen):
    pass


class CurrentStats(Screen):
    
    suggested_trainings = []
    trainings = []
    last_destroyed_item = None
    tr = []

    chance_ls_leg = [0, 0, 0]
    chance_ls_endurance = [0, 0, 0]
    chance_ls_coordination = [0, 0, 0]
    chance_ls_games = [0, 0, 0]

    current_training_1 = None
    current_training_2 = None
    current_training_3 = None
    current_training_4 = None

    sgst_tr_1 = StringProperty()
    sgst_tr_2 = StringProperty()
    sgst_tr_3 = StringProperty()
    sgst_tr_4 = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CurrentStats, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.create_suggested_training_list(4)

    def create_suggested_training_list(self, r):

        for i in range(0, r):
            self.trainings.append(random.sample(range(7), r)[i])

        print(self.trainings)

        for i in self.trainings:

            if i == 0:
                self.suggested_trainings.append("Leg Weight Training")

            elif i == 1:
                self.suggested_trainings.append("Endurance Training")

            elif i == 2:
                self.suggested_trainings.append("Coordination Training")

            elif i == 3:
                self.suggested_trainings.append("Play Games")

            elif i == 4:
                self.suggested_trainings.append("Core strength")

            elif i == 5:
                self.suggested_trainings.append("Upper Body")

            elif i == 6:
                self.suggested_trainings.append("lower abs")

        self.sgst_tr_1 = self.suggested_trainings[0]
        self.sgst_tr_2 = self.suggested_trainings[1]
        self.sgst_tr_3 = self.suggested_trainings[2]
        self.sgst_tr_4 = self.suggested_trainings[3]

        print(self.suggested_trainings)

    def destroy_first_suggested_training(self):
        self.current_training_1 = self.suggested_trainings[0]

        if self.current_training_1 == "Leg Weight Training":
            self.decr_chance_leg(1)

        elif self.current_training_1 == "Endurance Training":
            self.decr_chance_endurance(1)

        elif self.current_training_1 == "Coordination Training":
            self.decr_chance_coordination(1)

        elif self.current_training_1 == "Play Games":
            self.decr_chance_games(1)

        print(self.chance_ls_leg)

        del self.suggested_trainings[0]
        self.trainings = []
        self.create_suggested_training_list(1)
        print(self.suggested_trainings)

    def destroy_second_suggested_training(self):
        self.current_training_2 = self.suggested_trainings[1]

        if self.current_training_2 == "Leg Weight Training":
            self.decr_chance_leg(1)

        elif self.current_training_2 == "Endurance Training":
            self.decr_chance_endurance(1)

        elif self.current_training_2 == "Coordination Training":
            self.decr_chance_coordination(1)

        elif self.current_training_2 == "Play Games":
            self.decr_chance_games(1)

        del self.suggested_trainings[1]
        self.trainings = []
        self.create_suggested_training_list(1)
        print(self.suggested_trainings)
        print(self.trainings)

    def destroy_third_suggested_training(self):
        self.current_training_3 = self.suggested_trainings[2]

        if self.current_training_3 == "Leg Weight Training":
            self.decr_chance_leg(1)

        elif self.current_training_3 == "Endurance Training":
            self.decr_chance_endurance(1)

        elif self.current_training_3 == "Coordination Training":
            self.decr_chance_coordination(1)

        elif self.current_training_3 == "Play Games":
            self.decr_chance_games(1)

        del self.suggested_trainings[2]
        self.trainings = []
        self.create_suggested_training_list(1)
        print(self.suggested_trainings)

    def destroy_fourth_suggested_training(self):
        self.current_training_4 = self.suggested_trainings[3]

        if self.current_training_4 == "Leg Weight Training":
            self.decr_chance_leg(1)

        elif self.current_training_4 == "Endurance Training":
            self.decr_chance_endurance(1)

        elif self.current_training_4 == "Coordination Training":
            self.decr_chance_coordination(1)

        elif self.current_training_4 == "Play Games":
            self.decr_chance_games(1)

        del self.suggested_trainings[3]
        self.trainings = []
        self.create_suggested_training_list(1)
        print(self.suggested_trainings)


class RecentTrainings(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RecentTrainings, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def update(self):
        print("In Function: " + str(main.TrainingApp.recent_trainings))
        for training in main.TrainingApp.recent_trainings:
            print("recent trainings list: " + str(main.TrainingApp.recent_trainings))
            btn = Button(background_normal="training_programs/Unknown-" + str(training) + ".jpeg", size_hint=(.3, .15))
            lbl = Label(text="Training" + str(training), size_hint=(.5, .15))
            btn_show = Button(size_hint=(.2, .15), text="Show")

            self.ids.recentplans_grdlayout.add_widget(btn)
            self.ids.recentplans_grdlayout.add_widget(lbl)
            self.ids.recentplans_grdlayout.add_widget(btn_show)


class TrainingApp(MDApp):
    recent_trainings = []

    def build(self):
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(MainWindow(name="mainwindow"))
        self.sm.add_widget(TrainingPlans(name="trainingplans"))
        self.sm.add_widget(SingleTrainingPlan(name="singletrainingplan"))
        self.sm.add_widget(FavouriteTrainings(name="favouritetrainings"))
        self.sm.add_widget(NavigationDrawer(name="navigationdrawer"))
        self.sm.add_widget(CurrentStats(name="currentstats"))
        self.sm.add_widget(RecentTrainings(name="recenttrainings"))
        

        self.favouritetrainings = FavouriteTrainings()
        self.fav_training_content = self.favouritetrainings.ids.fav_tr_content

        return self.sm

    def do_cool_stuff(self):
        print("doing cool stuff")
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_app = TrainingApp()
    main_app.run()
```

second py file called `alltrainingplans.py`:

```
    from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
import os

import main
from main import *


class FavouriteTrainingsContent(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FavouriteTrainingsContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def refresh(self):
        print("i am in favourite trainings refresh")
        print("Favorite Plans:", main.FavouriteTrainings.fav_plans)

        for plan in main.FavouriteTrainings.fav_plans:
            print(plan)
            lbl = Label(
                size_hint=(.7, 1),
                text="Training " + str(plan)
            )

            btn = Button(
                size_hint=(.3, 1),
                background_normal="training_programs/Unknown-" + str(plan) + ".jpeg"
            )

            btn_show = Button(
                text="Show", size_hint=(.2, 1)
            )

            self.add_widget(btn)
            self.add_widget(lbl)
            self.add_widget(btn_show)


class GrdLayoutPlans(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GrdLayoutPlans, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        Clock.schedule_once(self.start_func, 2)

    def start_func(self, dt):
        list_training_plans = os.listdir("training_programs")  # dir is your directory path
        number_files = len(list_training_plans)
        plan_index = 1

        print("refreshing")

        singletrainingplan = main.SingleTrainingPlan()

        for plan in range(1, number_files):
            btn = Button(background_normal="training_programs/Unknown-" + str(plan_index) + ".jpeg", size_hint=(.3, 1))

            lbl = Label(text="Training" + str(plan_index))

            btn_show = Button(
                text="Show", size_hint=(.2, 1), on_relese=lambda x: singletrainingplan.show_training(plan)
            )

            self.add_widget(btn)
            self.add_widget(lbl)
            self.add_widget(btn_show)

            plan_index += 1


class ContentNavDrawer(BoxLayout):
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()
```

kv code:

```
MainWindow:

<MainWindow>
    name: "mainwindow"

    RelativeLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 0

            Line:
                width: 2
                points: 0, self.height*.96, self.width, self.height*.96

        CurrentStats:

        NavigationDrawer:

<CurrentStats>
    name: "currentstats"

    RelativeLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .9
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}

        canvas:

            Color:
                rgb: 1, 0, 0

            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

            Color:
                rgb: 0, 0, 0

            Line:
                width: 2
                points: self.width * 0.55, self.height - 2, self.width * 0.55, 0

            Line:
                width: 2
                points: 2, self.height * .9, self.width, self.height * .9

        FloatLayout:

            Label:
                text: "Your Progress this Week:"
                font_size: 24
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": 1.43}
                halign: "left"


            Label:
                text: "Weight Training"
                font_size: 20
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": 1.23}
                align: "center"

            Label:
                text: "Endurance Training"
                font_size: 20
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": 1.03}
                halign: "left"

            Label:
                text: "Coordination"
                font_size: 20
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": .83}
                halign: "left"

            Label:
                text: "Games"
                font_size: 20
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                text_size: self.size
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .52, "center_y": .63}
                halign: "left"



        Label:
            text: "Next Trainings"
            font_size: 20
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": 1.43}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"

        Label:
            text: root.sgst_tr_1
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": 1.23}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"

        Label:
            text: root.sgst_tr_2
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": 1.03}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"

        Label:
            text: root.sgst_tr_3
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": .83}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"

        Label:
            text: root.sgst_tr_4
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1.08, "center_y": .63}
            color: (0, 0, 0)
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"


        RelativeLayout:
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1, "center_y": 0}
            size_hint: .1, .8


            Button:
                text: "Delete"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": 1.42}
                on_release: root.destroy_first_suggested_training()

            Button:
                text: "Delete"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": 1.16}
                on_release: root.destroy_second_suggested_training()

            Button:
                text: "Delete"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": .9}
                on_release: root.destroy_third_suggested_training()

            Button:
                text: "Delete"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": .64}
                on_release: root.destroy_fourth_suggested_training()



            Button:
                text: "Show"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": 1.33}
                on_release:
                    app.root.get_screen('singletrainingplan').show_training(1)
                    app.root.current = "singletrainingplan"

            Button:
                text: "Show"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": 1.07}
                on_release:
                    app.root.get_screen('singletrainingplan').show_training(2)
                    app.root.current = "singletrainingplan"


            Button:
                text: "Show"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": .81}
                on_release:
                    app.root.get_screen('singletrainingplan').show_training(3)
                    app.root.current = "singletrainingplan"


            Button:
                text: "Show"
                color: (0, 0, 0)
                size_hint: 1, .1
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": .55}
                on_release:
                    app.root.get_screen('singletrainingplan').show_training(4)
                    app.root.current = "singletrainingplan"



<SingleTrainingPlan>
    name: "singletrainingplan"

    FloatLayout:
        size_hint_y: 1
        pos_hint: {"y": .3}
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 1, 1, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

        Image:
            source: root.path_i
            size: self.width, self.height
            allow_stretch: True

        NavigationDrawer:

    FloatLayout:
        size_hint_y: .1
        pos_hint: {"y": .1}

        Button:
            text: "back"
            size_hint: .3, 1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .2, "center_y": .1}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "mainwindow"

        Button:
            id: fav_btn
            size_hint: .2, 1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1}
            on_release:
                root.add_plan_to_favs()


<FavouriteTrainingsContent>
    size_hint_x: 1
    size_hint_y: None
    cols: 3
    height: self.minimum_height
    row_default_height: 150
    row_force_default: True
    size: root.size


<FavouriteTrainings>
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (0, 0, 0)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: .85
        size_hint_x: 1
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        FavouriteTrainingsContent:
            id: fav_tr_content

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1.006, .051
        pos_hint: {"x": -.003, "y": .85}

        TextInput:
            text: "Hello"
            background_color: (.22,.22,.22,1)

    NavigationDrawer:







<ContentNavDrawer>
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Home"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "mainwindow"
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Trainingplans"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "trainingplans"
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Favourites"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "favouritetrainings"
                    app.do_cool_stuff()
                    app.root.get_screen('favouritetrainings').ids.fav_tr_content.refresh()
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Recent Trainings"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "recenttrainings"
                    app.root.get_screen("recenttrainings").update()
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")

            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Settings"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "trainingplans"
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")



<NavigationDrawer>

    MDToolbar:
        size_hint: 1, .1
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        title: "Navigation Drawer"
        elevation: 8
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]

    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        ContentNavDrawer:
            nav_drawer: nav_drawer


<TrainingPlans>
    name: "trainingplans"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (0, 0, 0)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: .85
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": 0}
        do_scroll_x: False
        do_scroll_y: True

        GrdLayoutPlans:
            cols: 3
            width: root.width

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1.006, .051
        pos_hint: {"x": -.003, "y": .85}

        TextInput:
            text: "Hello"
            background_color: (.22,.22,.22,1)

    NavigationDrawer:

<GrdLayoutPlans>
    size_hint_x: None
    size_hint_y: None
    cols: 2
    height: self.minimum_height
    row_default_height: 150
    row_force_default: True



<RecentTrainings>
    width: root.width
    height: root.height

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (0, 0, 0)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size

    GridLayout:
        id: recentplans_grdlayout
        size_hint_y: .9
        cols: 3
        rows: 5
        row_default_height: root.height*.9/5
        row_force_default: True

    NavigationDrawer:
```

Comment: Please trim your code in order to reproduce it. Also address the issue you are facing with error code (if any).

Comment: @ApuCoder Thats the problem. there isn't an error or anything just nothing gets drawn on the screen. And I honestly don't know how i can trim the code to get the same problem so i will just upload the whole code to reproduce.

Comment: @ApuCoder I just uploaded the code. hope it works thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `start_func()` the line:

```
singletrainingplan = main.SingleTrainingPlan()
```

is creating a new instance of `SingleTrainingPlan`, so the `Button` defined later is trying to call a method of the new instance. But that new instance is not the one in your GUI. You should get the correct instance of `SingleTrainingPlan` by replacing the above line with:

```
singletrainingplan = MDApp.get_running_app().root.get_screen('singletrainingplan')
```

Then you can define the `Button` as :

```
        btn_show = Button(
            text="Show", size_hint=(.2, 1),
            on_release=partial(singletrainingplan.show_training, plan)
        )
```

And a slight change to the signature of the `show_training()` method:

```
def show_training(self, current_training, button_instance):
```

and to display the `SingleTrainingPlan` `Screen`, add this line to the end of the `show_training()` method:

```
self.manager.current = 'singletrainingplan'
```